# Entity Framework is installed, but is not accessible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, win-universal-app, uwp

I have installed **Entity Framework 6.1.3** from NuGet in a **Class Library** (Universal Windows), however I can't seem to access any of Entity Framework's namespaces.

I've tried `System.Data.Entity.` which brings back no intellisense.

Also, I've tried simply typing the `DbContext` class name, and attempted to resolve the name with no luck.

Rebuilding, cleaning, restarting Visual Studio doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: EF 6 doesn't support PCL.

Comment: Are you calling it within the class library or a separate project? e.g. Web project into a class library?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I assumed that as it installed from Nuget, things would be fine and dandy. Any ideas what I can do in this situation?

Comment: @christiandev Yes, I'm calling it in the same assembly.

Comment: EF 7 is supposed to have PCL support.  Depending on where you are in terms of your development, you might be fine to use it.  Best reference I could find: https://darkin.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/asp-net-vnext-community-standup-4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've solved the issue.

As Brendan Green mentioned, Entity Framework 6 does not support **PCL (Portable Class Library)**. However the next version, **Entity Framework 7** will. This is available on [GitHub right now](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework).

Also see [Getting Started on Universal Windows Platform](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html).