# How to use SQLite with Entity Framework 6 on UWP?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, uwp

I am now developing model classes for Universal Windows Application. Is there any possibility to use EF6 and SQLite together in this project or should I use pre-release of EF7 only?

Comment: Per [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32629144/50447), EF6 is not supported on UWP, so you'll have to wait (like me) for EF7 which is not yet ready for use in apps distributed via the store :(

Comment: @RowlandShaw Thanks!

Comment: FYI: there are also some ongoing issues with .net native https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/623

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can now use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`, but with a little workaround needed.

[Useful documentation](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/#SFYr6se4X1MPMUwi.97)

[A useful walkthrough](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html#create-your-database)

Workarounds:

[adding an app.config to application layer UWP## Heading ##](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6551)

[Add Ms.EfCore.Tools to app layer (natemcmaster commented on 3 May)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5069)

Hope this helps